# 400 bad request when form is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm struggling with this issue for two days, I'm a bit new in .net core. I'm getting 400 bad request and the request does not hit my action only when I post an invalid form(required fields are empty)  Is this normal? if so why my error validation message does not show?!
If not normal is it something to do with middleware?
Here is my code

My Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
    public IActionResult Save([FromForm] myModel model)
    {
        string message = "";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            message = "product " + model.DecisionDate + " created successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        return Content(message);
    }
```

My form:

```
      <form id="msform" class="form-horizontal" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-url="Save">

         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DecisionDate)
         <input type="datetime-local" asp-for="DecisionDate" class="form-control text-right" name="DecisionDate" placeholder="Email">
                                   
         <textarea class="form-control" name="Notes" rows="3"></textarea>
         <input type="submit" name="next" class="next action-button" value="save"/>
      </form>
```

My Model:

```
public class myModel
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Decision date cannot be empty")]
    public DateTime? DecisionDate { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i think u need to define which controller ajax is gonna use, if i'm not wrong we were setting that url like ```"data-ajax-url="/Home/Save"``` . here is a example: ibb.co/wL9Y5p8

Comment: @BerkGarip It's already set and the request hits the action when the form is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution in case someone face the same problem, it's a middleware issue, I added this and it works fine:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true)
```